# CSS animation shorthand property syntax order

Tags: css

If the order of values for the CSS animation shorthand property are as such : animation: [name] [duration] [timing-function] [delay] [iteration-count] [direction] [fill-mode] [play-state]; , how does the below CSS make sense?

`animation: coffee-labels-active 0.5s 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.645, 0.045, 0.355, 1) both;`

It appears that [delay] is coming before [timing-function] and that the fill mode is `both`. 
Are we able to play around with the order of these values?

Comment: I see you never responded to the answer, hope you rate it or mark it if you found it helpful. Cheers

Comment: Thanks Highdef!  Great explanation.  Gave it an up vote.  For newer coders like myself, it would be helpful if the values followed some strict order so I know what value I'm looking at.

Comment: You could mark it since no one else answered it but anyways your welcome :)

Answer (score 3):

Actually, it seems that the animation shorthand property doesn't follow a strict order as many of the other CSS syntaxes do. Here's an example:

For the class element we have got the `timing function, followed by delay`.

For the class element2 we have got `delay followed by timing function`.

For the class element3, I `randomized all of the animation properties` and still the output is same.

Hence, we can conclude what we assumed.

```css
.element {
  height: 250px;
  width: 250px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: red;
  animation: stretch 1.5s ease-out 0s alternate infinite none running;
}

.element2 {
  height: 250px;
  width: 250px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: red;
  animation: stretch 1.5s 0s ease-out alternate infinite none running;
}

.element3 {
  height: 250px;
  width: 250px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: red;
  animation: stretch ease-out 1.5s  none running 0s  alternate infinite ;
}

@keyframes stretch {
  0% {
    transform: scale(.3);
    background-color: red;
    border-radius: 100%;
  }
  50% {
    background-color: orange;
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(1);
    background-color: yellow;
  }
}

body,
html {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="element"></div>

<div class="element2"></div>

<div class="element3"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Not completely randomised - 1.5s always precedes 0s in your example.

1.5s = `animation-duration`
0s = `animation delay`

If you reversed the order so that 0s preceded 1.5s the animation wouldn't run.

So, `animation-duration` always precedes `animation-delay`.

In the following example, the animation on `<div class="element element2"></div>` won't run.

```
    .element {
        height: 250px;
        width: 250px;
    }

    .element1 {
        background-color: red;

        /* 1.5 seconds duration / 0 seconds delay */
        animation: changeColor 1.5s 0s;
    }

    .element2 {
        background-color: red;

        /* 0 seconds duration / 1.5 seconds delay */
        animation: changeColor 0s 1.5s;
    }

    @keyframes changeColor {
        from { background:red;}
        to { background: green; }
    }

<div class="element element1">1</div>


<div class="element element2">2</div>
```

The rest of the properties do seem to be randomised.

Apologies if I'm stating the bleeding obvious (I had to check it out for myself as I wasn't sure).

Comment: Great explanation, as you mentioned, 0s duration with 1s delay is non-sense. so first time value must be duration value

Answer (score 1):

From [the specification](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-animations/#animation) you can see the formal syntax as

```
<single-animation> = <time> || <easing-function> || <time> || <single-animation-iteration-count> || <single-animation-direction> || <single-animation-fill-mode> || <single-animation-play-state> || [ none | <keyframes-name> ]
```

Where `||` means

> A double bar (`||`) separates two or more options: one or more of them must occur, in **any order**. <sup>[ref](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-values-4/#comb-any)</sup>

In that same specification you will also find some extra rules related to parsing the `<time>` since we have two of them and also `<keyframes-name>`

> Note that order is important within each animation definition: the first value in each `<single-animation>` that can be parsed as a `<time>` is assigned to the `animation-duration`, and the second value in each `<single-animation>` that can be parsed as a `<time>` is assigned to `animation-delay`.

> Note that order is also important within each animation definition for distinguishing `<keyframes-name>` values from other keywords. When parsing, keywords that are valid for properties other than `animation-name` whose values were not found earlier in the shorthand must be accepted for those properties rather than for `animation-name`.

In other words, you can use any order you want but if you will use two `<time>` then the first one is the duration and the second one is the delay and all the known keywords will be assigned to their respective property